# xtrabackup: too many open files (more than 1048576)

Tags: linux-kernel, ulimit, xtrabackup

When using xtrabackup to backup a mysql database with lots of tables, the proces fails with Error 24: ‘Too many open files’.

This is a FAQ on the Percona website: https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-xtrabackup/2.2/faq.html#backup-fails-with-error-24-too-many-open-files

My problem is that I cannot increase the allowed number of file descriptors any further, because the Linux kernel has a hard coded open file limit of 1048576.

Does anybody know:

- If we can configure xtrabackup in a way that will open less tables (or less concurrently)?
- How we can increase the kernel open file limit of 1048576?

Comment: Your database directory *really* has over 1 milion files?

Comment: Yes, more than 2M: `ll | wc -l: 2023694`

Comment: It is an extremely corner case, really. I think you should contact Percona to get more accurate information.

Comment: Ok thanks. I think we will rewrite the application to use less tables. I suspect there might be other problems ahead if the number keeps growing like this.